# Beginning regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have absolutely no idea about regex at all. I am trying to perform email validation in a PHP signup script (to check if a valid email has been entered). I have got a script from the internet but I don't know how it works and I am completely unfamiliar with the functions used. I found out that the function they used (`eregi_replace()`) is deprecated in favor of `preg_replace()`. Firstly, can someone guide me through the steps of the function below, and secondly can you explain the `preg_replace()` function and how it works?
The validation script:

```
$regex = "([a-z0-9_.-]+)". # name
            "@". # at
            "([a-z0-9.-]+){2,255}". # domain & possibly subdomains
            ".". # period
            "([a-z]+){2,10}"; # domain extension 
        $eregi = eregi_replace($regex, '', $email);
        $valid_email = empty($eregi) ? true : false;
```

The script was sourced from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/55133/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regex are not needed here:

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

if you want training i suggest you to visit http://www.regular-expressions.info and http://php.net

To quickly test a pattern you can use this online tool: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Comment: Thank you! What is that function?

Comment: @imulsion: php has a lot of validation filters, see:http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php